# Is using BINARY_CHECKSUM a good way to keep two databases in sync?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to work with a database which keeps a track of instances of certain events on a network. I want to be able to keep my own copy of those on another database elsewhere.

The issue I have is keeping in sync with updates. If a record changes on database A I want to then update database B with the changes. Simple enough but database A doesn't have any form of modified timestamp field, and I cannot change the database at all (not even to add triggers). I am writing a C# application which will be doing the syncronisation on an hourly basis. (This is acceptable to my requirements, data doesn't have to be fresh all of the time).

My question is this:

If I use BINARY_CHECKSUM, I can presumably keep a list elsewhere (memory/XML/whatever) of the expected value, then periodically check to see if it is different. If it is different I can then sync the row manually in code.

Is this a good idea? Is there a large overhead associated with BINARY_CHECKSUM? Is there a better way to detect changes to a row that I cannot change?

**EDIT**: I am fully aware of SQL replication, however I should have mentioned that the two databases are not on the same network, and interfacing between them is done via web services accessed by C#.

Cheers,

Comment: "If a record changes on database A I want to then update database B with the changes" - use [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)?

Comment: I know about replication, but it is not possible in this case, especially considering the two databases have different schemas, hence the c# in the middle to do some marshalling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted this in a comment to Jobo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14157430/15498):

```
declare @t table (
    ColA int not null,
    ColB int not null,
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key
)
insert into @t values (1,0)
select BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) from @t

update @t set ColA = 0,ColB = 16 where ID = 1
select BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) from @t
```

Result:

```
-----------
257

-----------
257
```

So no, I wouldn't recommend `BINARY_CHECKSUM` as a means to keep databases in sync.

Remember that any form of hashing is a good means to determine that two inputs are definitely different (if the result of the hash is different), but if the results are the same, you usually have to check all of the specific values to determine if the inputs are really the same or just have the same hash value.

The exception is if you're using a balanced hash function of sufficient length that collisions are so unlikely that you won't see one in your lifetime. `int`, at 32 bits, is not long enough.

Comment: Accepting this as my answer to the original question. It turns out BINARY_CHECKSUM isn't exactly what I expected it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As it seems the table in question doesn´t even have a PK i would not consider BINARY_CHECKSUM anymore.

I think you would have to compute the hash with better function like SHA256 or even higher in your client code.

Comment: `BINARY_CHECKSUM` returns `int`. If you're alluding to collisions, you only need ~80000 rows for the chance of a collision to be > 50%

Comment: As I read the question - detect change to a single row.  How does a collision across rows apply?   Assume has PK as "update database B".

Comment: @Damien true, but i think he has some identifier also? he wants to compare the checksum of the same record. not every checksum of every record against each other. the chance that the same record leads to the same checksum although the record was changed seems unlikely 'enough' for me

Comment: @Jobo Based on a single record at a time the number of rows is not applicable so why the reference to trillions?

Comment: Have you not seen my [counter example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14160250/15498)? - originally a comment to your answer, now posted independently. `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is *very easy* to construct collisions for.

Comment: Just read it, wonder what microsoft did there, good to know. i still think can be ok to use BINARY_CHECKSUM depending on the tables and the scenario.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, but I have upvoted this one anyway. I think I am going to do something "higher in the client" as you put it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot even change the target DB?

If any PK is an identity then you will also need to map PK.

If the PK is data then if the PK is changed you know there was a change but then how are you going to know which row it maps to?

Now in a comment we find out there is no PK and synch from multiple.

Without a PK there is NO "update database B with the changes".
At best you can insert any row the does not match.
You don't know if it is a new row or edit to a row.
With any hashing you have a chance of collision to miss a row.
If you expect hourly synch hope you don't have many rows.

Comment: The issue is that the target DB will be taking data in this fashion from multiple source DB's.

Comment: The even better news is that the person who designed the source table wasn't so kind as to give it a PK...

Comment: Then you need to update the question with this detail.   Database A and B reflect two.